# All falling objects freeze - why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics

Hi there I have spent about an hour making some edits to my project only to find that for some reason all the cubes, that I had set to fall and bounce on the plane, now simply hover in mid air.

I have uploaded the project in question below. (or will try to)
I would be very grateful of any help.
[Google Drive Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGe-nHf9cwRdXh3cl9POXVfelk/view?usp=sharing)

This question was removed as of apparently being solved by an answer given to another question which referenced to reseting the rigid body world cache. This would make sense as I have been editing the FPS. However I have never enabled rigid body world. And it has worked perfectly fine before. I actually originally downloaded this project as a template put have since heavily modified it. I have re downloaded that template and found that it too of course does not have a rigid body world enabled. I can not find out what is wrong because I have realised that I don't know how the cubes ever managed to fall to the ground.

Here is a link to the original template that I used.
[Google Drive Original template blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGe-nHf9cwRdXh3cl9POXVfelk/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for the quick response that I previously received.

Comment: If you haven't enabled rigid body, how did you get the physics to work? Did you add keyframes manually?

Comment: As I said the project is based on a template. I assumed that indeed rigid body world had been enabled for the physics of the cubes. So I really don't know how they were working before and how they should be now. That is why it is so difficult for me to work this out. So no I did not add keyframes. None of the cubes appear on the dope sheet as far as I can see.

Comment: They're soft bodies. Go into the physics tab, and click on the Soft Body Cache. It says the cache is outdated. Click Bake and try playing it again.

Comment: @SixthOfFour thank you so much it all works fine now. You have saved me hours of trial and error.

Comment: You're welcome. I voted to reopen. If I can get enough people to ageree, I'll add this as an answer. Though it's quite possible that this may considered similar enough to the "duplicate" that it will remain closed.